# SQL Server 2016 Cannot add system versioning to relationship table

Tags: sql-server-2016

The SQL Server 2016 system versioning is cool. I am using the free Developer version. Thanks MS!

I am unable to figure out if it will give me versioning of many to many relationships. I have a User object that has a collection of Roles and vice versa. Entity Framework has generated the `UserRoles` table that holds the relationship between `User` and `Roles`. I was able to turn on system versioning for the `User` and `Roles` tables using this article http://sqlhints.com/tag/modify-existing-table-as-system-versioned-temporal-table/.

But, I am not able to turn on for `UserRoles`. I get an error

> Setting SYSTEM_VERSIONING to ON failed because table has a FOREIGN KEY with cascading DELETE or UPDATE.

Does this mean we cannot know the versioning for many-many relationships?

For eg.

- on 6/1 - User1 had role1 and role2, but
- on 6/4 - User1's role changed to role1 and role3

So, if I wanted to know the state of the user on 6/1, I thought that's possible only by turning on system versioning on `UserRoles`, but that's not working.

Is this doable or not supported by SQL Server 2016? If not, is there any other way this can be accomplished?

Comment: Sounds like it's the ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE DELETE foreign key that's the issue. Remove the cascading and replace that with a delete proc that knows and handles the proper relationships and you should be fine.

Comment: That's what we ended up doing. Thanks a lot! Wonder how I can mark that as answer.

Comment: I'll drop it into the "Answer" section so it can show up as answered. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it's the ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE DELETE foreign key that's the issue. Remove the cascading and replace that with a delete proc that knows and handles the proper relationships and you should be fine.

Personally, I like knowing what my deletes/updates are doing rather than trusting the relationships to handle all of them. I can see potential locking issues as well as know that there are times I really want to prevent an update or delete rather than letting it cascade through all of the tables unseen.

Answer (score 14):

It's important to notice that the limitation of using `CASCADE` on `FOREIGN KEY` constraints in temporal tables is applicable only to SQL Server 2016. In SQL Server 2017, this limitation doesn't exist anymore.

This is the relevant part from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-considerations-and-limitations?view=sql-server-2017):

> ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are not permitted on the
>   current table. In other words, when temporal table is referencing
>   table in the foreign key relationship (corresponding to
>   parent_object_id in sys.foreign_keys) CASCADE options are not allowed.
>   To work around this limitation, use application logic or after
>   triggers to maintain consistency on delete in primary key table
>   (corresponding to referenced_object_id in sys.foreign_keys). If
>   primary key table is temporal and referencing table is non-temporal,
>   there's no such limitation.
>
> **> NOTE: This limitation applies to SQL Server 2016 only. CASCADE options
>   are supported in SQL Database and SQL Server 2017 starting from CTP
>   2.0.**

Comment: That's true. I've edited my answer following your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are not permitted on the current table. In other words, when temporal table is referencing table in the foreign key relationship (corresponding to parent_object_id in sys.foreign_keys) CASCADE options are not allowed. To work around this limitation, use application logic or after triggers to maintain consistency on delete in primary key table (corresponding to referenced_object_id in sys.foreign_keys). If primary key table is temporal and referencing table is non-temporal, there’s no such limitation.