# Windows API call "RegGetValueW" returned error code: 0

Tags: sql-server, ssms, localdb

I am getting Windows API Call Error Code :  0

I have installed SSMS 2018 and was trying to find out if I have any other versions installed. For that I ran `sqllocaldb versions` in CMD but got the following message:

> Windows API call "RegGetValueW" returned error code: 0.

When I checked manually (via Control Panel), I saw that I have 2015 and 2016 versions installed. So Why it are they not showing in CMD.

I tried to find other solutions but found nothing that made sense to me.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34222855--windows-api-call-reggetvaluew-error-when-displ

Answer (score 34):

This post helped me:
*https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1257bf26-6ab0-416d-bf26-34f128f42248/sql-2016-sp1-sqllocaldb-versions-errors-with-quotwindows-api-call-quotreggetvaluewquot?forum=sqlexpress*

In registry change catalog name in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions
```

to match the version listed in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion
```

I  my case I had to change from 13.0 to 13.1.

Comment: This also happens with Visual Studio 2019 (for me it's version 16.3.3) with a workload that includes SSDT/localDB. I logged a bug report here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/809670/vs-2019-163-that-includes-ssdt-sqllocaldb-command.html

Answer (score 22):

This is still an issue sometimes in 2020. daniell89's answer is correct, here is an image further explaining the fix.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I see that the answers above are correct. However, I would like to share how to fix it step by step.

First, open the Registry Editor. To do it make a combination on the keyboard: `Windows + R` and then type `regedit` and hit OK. The Registry Editor should appear.

Then find the installed current version under this path:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13E.LOCALDB \MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion`

In my case it was `13.1.4001.0`

Then go to Local DB registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions`

There you should have listed folders named as versions.
I had there a folder `13.0` which I have changed to `13.1`.

After the renamed of the folder the command `SQLLocalDB versions` works perfectly.