# sqllocaldb versions Windows API call "RegGetValueW" returned error code: 0

Tags: sql-server, ssms, localdb

I am very very new to database systems. You could say I have no idea what I am doing. But I have been hired for an internship that requires I learn.

To this purpose I installed SMSS 17.9 and somehow Microsoft SQL server 2017 but it didn't install SQLlocaldb. I also have VS 2019 and 2017 and for some reason, these also didn't install SQLlocaldb.

Therefore I installed SQLLocaldb by itself by after downloading SQLServer2017-SSEI and opting to download files to run later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15

Anyways, I found a tutorial on youtube and as the man is starting, he runs

"sqllocaldb versions". For him it shows his SQL server versions. For me I get:
"Windows API call "RegGetValueW" returned error code: 0"

So I googled to find solutions to this. Most of them have to do with changing registry version values as shown here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1257bf26-6ab0-416d-bf26-34f128f42248/sql-2016-sp1-sqllocaldb-versions-errors-with-quotwindows-api-call-quotreggetvaluewquot?forum=sqlexpress

[Windows API call "RegGetValueW" returned error code: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760683/windows-api-call-reggetvaluew-returned-error-code-0)

However for me I have this issue where there is no version key in my registry:
[image]

**Why don't I see a version for my LocalDB?**

The solution was to go to the version key and change it to match with the version of SQLServer like in this example:

[image]

Comment: Literally having this exact same problem and am finding no luck.