# Blazor WebAssembly App with Individual Accounts and ASP.NET Core Hosted - IIS - SQLLocalDB 15.0 The specified resource language ID cannot be found

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Creating a new `Blazor WebAssembly App` with `Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.9.4` with these specifications: `Target Framework .NET 5.0`, `Authentication Type Individual Accounts` and `ASP.NET Core Hosted`:

[image]

With no modifications I have simply started the project with `IIS Express`, ran migrations and added a user to the database.

This works without a problem so then I created a publish profile to folder.

[image]

I then set up a new site in IIS, version 10.0.19041.1, and set the Application Pool to use my Windows Identity that I have confirmed works with `SSMS` and that works via `IIS Express`.

[image]

[image]

Running it the first time I got this error in Windows logs:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.<>c.b__10_2(IServiceProvider
> sp)

I fixed this by adding a `Key` to `IdentityServer` in `appsettings.json` exactly like `appsettings.Development.json` does it:

```
"Key": {
  "Type": "Development"
}
```

After this I receive errors I have never seen before:

> SQLLocalDB 15.0 Windows API call WaitForMultipleObjects returned error
> code: 575. Windows system error message is: {Application Error} The
> application was unable to start correctly (0x%lx). Click OK to close
> the application. Reported at line: 3714.
>
> SQLLocalDB 15.0 Windows API call FormatMessageW returned error code:
> 1815. Windows system error message is: The specified resource language ID cannot be found in the image file. Reported at line: 4296.

[image]

After these errors there is the standard connection error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 50 - Local
> Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB
> instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.

The application pool uses the same Identity that I use to sign in to `SSMS` and that runs `IIS Express`. I have made it work like this using `LocalDB 13.1` previously but I had to upgrade my LocalDB in order to use `Temporal tables`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64210519/3850405

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: This may be a permission issue, there is a similar issue in this link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30383/cannot-start-sqllocaldb-instance-with-my-windows-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried sharing based on the comment by @DingPeng but I still got the same error.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30384/80960

[image]

Checked the logs at `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\mssqllocaldb`.

> 2021-05-12 00:08:24.41 Logon       Login failed for user
> '*******-*******\Oscar'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly
> specified database
> 'aspnet-WebApplication7.Server-'.
> [CLIENT: ]
>
> 2021-05-12 00:08:25.98 spid52      Starting up
> database
> 'aspnet-WebApplication7.Server-'.
>
> 2021-05-12 00:08:26.00 spid52      Parallel redo is started for
> database
> 'aspnet-WebApplication7.Server-'
> with worker pool size [4].
>
> 2021-05-12 00:08:26.02 spid52      Parallel
> redo is shutdown for database
> 'aspnet-WebApplication7.Server-'
> with worker pool size [4].

I then remembered that I actually had this problem with `SQLLocalDB 13.0` and `SQLLocalDB 13.1` as well. The danger of working late hours.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62810876/3850405

After following this answer I verified that `Load User Profile` was set to true for my `Application Pool` and then set `setProfileEnvironment` to `true` in `applicationHost.config`. I did the last part by editing `applicationHost.config` located at:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

[image]

After this everything worked!